# jQuery custom events work in global scope, but not between objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Please see demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/mA6qm/1/ (expand console)

Why aren't events being sent or received between two object yet the same code works fine when it's placed in the global scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the object you're binding the event to is not the same object you're triggering it on. In the `setTimeout` callback, `this` will not refer to `calling_object` even though you defined `finished` as a method on that object. Instead it will refer to the window. Similarly, when you bound the event the event was bound on `listening_object`. You need to make sure you're using the same object for both.

Comment: does it matter what 'this' is in the setTimeout callback? I'm just using it to get access to jQuery's .trigger. I could just as easily use $(document).trigger('test2')

Comment: Then I don't understand what your question is about. The problem you're having is _specifically_ because you bound the event on one object but triggered it on a different one.

Comment: See this tutorial on jQuery custom events: http://corymathews.com/jquery-custom-events/